# Word Meaning "Chopped Into Little Bits" (Ending With `-ize`)

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a word that means, roughly, to cut something into little bits.  I think it ended in `-ize`, and maybe had a cooking connotation.  I can't remember it.

> She put the carrots in the blender, and pressed the button to _____ize them.

Comment: *Mince, julienne, shred, grate, pulverize, vaporize*?

Comment: liquidize? [very tiny bits]

Comment: It slices, it dices!!

Comment: Osterize, an osterizer.

Comment: @bib Julienne, shred, and grate do not reduce something to "little bits." And I wouldn't want to be in your kitchen when you use a blender that can vaporize its contents.

Comment: @deadrat vaporize is bits so fine they are gaseous.

Comment: @bib Yeah, I'm familiar with the word.  I just don't want to be anywhere near a blender that can do that.  At least not when it's operating.

Comment: Press the button to *blitz* the carrots. Sorry, no -ize ending.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions 
[fragmentise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fragmentize)
Also,  [incise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incise)